# Taking "exit" as user input in C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to write code that takes user input as strings, and then convert them to integers if I need to. If the user decides to enter `exit` then the program should move on to calling a function. Here is what I have so far:

```
void printArray(string string_array[], int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << string_array[i];
    }

}
void a_func(){
    string string_array[10];
    string user_input;

    while (user_input != "exit"){
        cout << "Please enter a number between 0 - 100: ";
        cin >> user_input;
        if (stoi(user_input) < 0 || stoi(user_input) > 100){
            cout << "Error, please re-enter the number between 0 - 100: ";
            cin >> user_input;
        }
        else if (user_input == "exit"){
            printArray(string_array, 10);
        }
        int array_index = stoi(user_input) / 10;
        string_array[array_index] = "*";
}
```

However, as I'm testing the program, the console is aborting the program if I enter `exit`. Is there a way for me to enter exit and then the program calls `printArray`?

Comment: Where do you close the bracket of the `else if`? And of the `while` loop, and of the function? And anyway, you are calling `printArray(string_array)` but the function requires 2 arguments. This code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: homework? You are not showing relevant sections of your code.

Comment: @Fabio, Sorry, I did not copy and paste this directly from visual studios. I did not want to ask the direct problem, and so I came up with a smaller question that still needs to solve the `exit` problem. This is actually all of my code, sans `main()`, which just calls `a_function();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this changes in your code will solve the problem.  Please, try with this code:

```
void printArray(string string_array[], int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << string_array[i];
    }

}
void a_func(){
    string string_array[10];
    string user_input;

    while (user_input != "exit"){
        cout << "Please enter a number between 0 - 100: ";
        cin >> user_input;
        if (user_input == "exit"){
            printArray(string_array, 10);
        }
        else if (stoi(user_input) < 0 || stoi(user_input) > 100){
            cout << "Error, please re-enter the number between 0 - 100: ";
            cin >> user_input;

            int array_index = stoi(user_input) / 10;
            string_array[array_index] = "*";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

stoi doesn't accept non-numbers. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(string string_array[], int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << string_array[i];
    }
}

void a_func(){
    string string_array[10];
    string user_input;

    while (user_input != "exit"){
        cout << "Please enter a number between 0 - 100: ";
        cin >> user_input;
        //cout << "You have printed " << user_input << endl;

        bool isNumber = true;
        for(string::const_iterator k = user_input.begin(); k != user_input.end(); ++k) {
            if (isdigit(*k) == false) {
                isNumber = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isNumber) {
            int number = stoi(user_input);
            if (number < 0 || number > 100){
                cout << "Error, please re-enter the number between 0 - 100: ";
                continue;
            } else {
                int array_index = stoi(user_input) / 10;
                string_array[array_index] = "*";
            }
        } else if (user_input == "exit"){
            printArray(string_array, 10);
            break;
        } else {
            // Not a number and not "exit"; do nothing?
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    a_func();
    return 0;
}
```